# Setting class attribute to an element does not work with javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have these following lines of code:

jQuery

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "MM d, yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Javascript

```
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.setAttribute("class", "datepicker");
```

Suppose to be the element I created in javascript must be a datepicker, so I set its class to "datepicker" which was defined in the jQuery code. But this thing doesn't work.

Any possible solutions? Setting classes which are defined in css works for me, but this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing should work perfectly fine as long as the jQuery code runs *after* your element has been created **and** appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).append($('<input/>', {
  'class': 'datepicker',
   type: 'text'
})).on('click', function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "MM d, yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery for this?

```
$('input').addClass('datepicker');
```